# Vaadin 12 : Is it has Maven archetype?

Tags: maven-3, vaadin12

In official documentation of Vaadin 8 I found how use Maven archetype:

https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/getting-started/getting-started-archetypes.html

Ok. Something like this:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate \
        -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin \
        -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application \
        -DarchetypeVersion=8.3.3 \
        -DgroupId=org.test \
        -DartifactId=vaadin-app \
        -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Nice.

But what about Vaadin 12? Is it has Maven archetype ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no maven archetypes for Vaadin 10+ (yet).

You may however try these as long as there are no "official" archetypes.

https://github.com/viritin/vaadin-flow-archetypes

For example:

```
mvn archetype:generate  \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=in.virit  \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=viritin-vaadin-flow-archetype  \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.0
    -DgroupId=org.test \
    -DartifactId=vaadin-app \
    -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

But as of now I think the officially prefered way to create Vaadin 10+ projects is using a starter project from

https://vaadin.com/start/lts

where you can download a zip file containing a maven project setup.

Answer (score 0):

## *Update:* artifacts `vaadin-core` & `vaadin`

Maven artifacts are now available for [*Vaadin Flow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow), versions 10, 11, 12, 13, & 14.

If you want to restrict yourself to using only the free-of-cost non-commercial widgets from Vaadin Ltd, use [artifact `vaadin-core`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-core).

If you might want access to the commercial widgets as well as the free-of-cost widgets, use the [artifact `vaadin`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin).

You can grab the command-line text for creating an empty project via Maven by copying from the *Maven* tab of the [*Get started with Vaadin*](https://vaadin.com/start/latest) page. Currently:

> mvn -B archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST -DgroupId=org.test -DartifactId=vaadin-app -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT

And the *Download* tab on [that page](https://vaadin.com/start/latest) will create and download an entire Maven-driven project in any of 3 flavors:

- Spring Boot
- CDI & Java EE
- Plain Java Servlet

If you do not know about Spring or CDI, then use the third option, *Plain Java Servlet*. Expand the downloaded `.zip` file. Import the folder as a Maven project into your IDE such as IntelliJ, NetBeans, or Eclipse. You can immediately run your new web app via [*Jetty*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server)) [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) bundled via Maven.